# Push all local references and branches to git upstream

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have accidentally deleted some upstream branches in bitbucket while working on deleting outdated feature branches using script. in that branches I lost few important branches like develop and other few important feature branches. But in my local I have all the references to the branches that I deleted. Now I want to push my local version of copy to upstream. to override entire upstream repository with my local git repository. will that be possible? if possible please provide me the commands that I need to use.

Thanks!!

Comment: Just push your local branches.

`git push origin develop branch2 branch3`.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is push the local branches again and all should be good.

`git push <remote-name> <branch-name>` for each branch you deleted will do the trick. You can write a script to do this if you desire, but this is the only command you need from a `git` perspective.

Comment: `git push <remote> <branch-name>`

Comment: @phd Whoopsie! Thank you :)